# Reference request: Fréchet embedding

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry

Given a separable metric space $(X,d)$, we have an isometric embedding $\iota:X\to\ell^\infty$ given by taking $(x_n) _{n \ge 0}$ to be the countable dense subset and sending $\iota(x)_n=(d(x,x_n) - d(x_n,x_0))$. (Note the image of $\iota$ lies in $\ell^\infty$ since $\forall k.\iota(x)_k\leq d(x,x_0)<\infty$ by the triangle inequality)

This embedding is attributed to Kuratowski and Fréchet, but while I have a citation for the former (Kur35, theorem of section 6), the attributions to the latter occur in contexts where either no references are provided (Mat02, Chapter 1, p. 17), they point nowhere (Bar06), or they point to a 72-page paper which after three rereads doesn't *appear* to contain the construction (Wiki).

Does anyone actually have a reference to this, or is this a case of citogenesis?

[Kur35] Kuratowski, C. (1935) "Quelques problèmes concernant les espaces métriques non-separables" (Some problems concerning non-separable metric spaces), Fundamenta Mathematicae 25: pp. 534–545

[Mat02] J. Matoušek. Lectures on discrete geometry. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2002

[Bar06] Bartal, Yair, et al. “Limitations to Fréchet’s Metric Embedding Method.” Israel Journal of Mathematics, vol. 151, no. 1, Dec. 2006, pp. 111–24. Crossref, https://doi.org/10.1007/bf02777357.

[Wiki] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_embedding, pointing to Fréchet M. (1906) "Sur quelques points du calcul fonctionnel", Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo 22: 1–74.

Comment: Note that the Kuratowski paper cited here, unlike the Fréchet papers cited below, makes the technically unnecessary assumption that the space is bounded (which may have contributed to the mistaken edit adding this assumption). It makes sense for that paper though, given it's considering bounded functionals from Banach spaces, but the "subtract $d(x_n,x_0)$" trick works equally well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me preface this by thanking you for saving my sanity. I started looking for the same reference this evening and was equally led astray by Wikipedia, and I was starting to doubt of my literacy when googling pointed me to your question. Instead of going at it a fourth or fifth time of my own, I started looking elsewhere, and I found it (page 162):

Fréchet, M.. "Les dimensions d'un ensemble abstrait." Mathematische Annalen 68 (1910): 145-168. http://eudml.org/doc/158434.

There's also this later article where he repeats the proof:

Frechet, Maurice. “L’Expression La Plus Generale de La ‘Distance’ Sur Une Droite.” American Journal of Mathematics, vol. 47, no. 1, 1925, pp. 1–10. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/2370698. Accessed 16 Mar. 2024.

As an extra tidbit, in the second one at the very end he also conjectures the existence of the Urysohn Space! I'll fix Wikipedia if I remember...

I think whomever put that other article on Wikipedia was led astray by the fact that it is the first place (I think, I might be entirely wrong) where he defined the $\ell^\infty$ space.

Comment: Joyous day! Thank you!

Comment: It's interesting to note the various uses to which this embedding has been put -- the two Fréchet papers you cite use it respectively to show $\ell^\infty$ is a "universal" separable metric space (despite not being separable itself), and to pull back a metric from an arbitrary simple Jordan curve. In contrast, the Kuratowkski paper uses it to show any metric space is homeomorphic to a Banach space, while the Matoušek notes I cite use it as an archetypical example of a non-distorting mapping. Math is beautiful!

Comment: And I nearly was led astray by that article _again_, since the 1925 paper you cite mentions it -- having only glanced at the referring sentence, I missed that it was referring to the Rendiconti paper only as a source for the space of sequences with uniform convergence -- he then equips it with a metric and cuts out $\ell^\infty$ out of his ambient space.

Comment: Correction -- the second paper, IIUC, attempts to construct all metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ as pullbacks of metrics on an arbitrary Jordan curve in $\ell^\infty$

Comment: I added the edit to Wikipedia. Would be glad if you could go over it, see if there's anything you can add.

Comment: I think the wikipedia edit is perfectly goof.

Comment: Sorry, I meant “good”!